# Apache NIFI InvokeHttp in a loop fails

Tags: apache-nifi

I have an `invokeHTTP` processor where the in the remoteURL I have to add the page number for which I get the data. Following is my process workflow

1. Get the total no.of records for a given URL using `invokeHTTP` and I use the `EvaluateXPath` to store the `totalRecords` and initialize the `startIndex` to 1.
2. I added `RouteOnAttribute` to check if my `startIndex` is less than `totalRecords` and if more then I stop.
3. I do the `invokeHTTP` where in the remote URL I pass the `startIndex` .
4. If I get response, then I increment the `startIndex` by 100 and send it back to `RounteOnAttribute` in step 2.

The issue I am having is when the `startIndex` gets incremented and goes back to `invokeHTTP` the processor just hangs.. when I stop and restart the `invokeHTTP` it works but then hangs on the loop again. Not Sure what I am doing wrong here ?

I included my screenshot of the processing as well...
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I fixed my issue.. It was due to the fact that I used Expression with string concatenation in my `invokeHTTP`.. When I changed and added `UpdateAttribute` which did the URL building and then use that in `invokeHTTP` seems to have fixed the issue..

Earlier in my `invokeHTTP` I had the `RemoteURL` property set to `http://example.com?startIndex=${startIndex}` and this did not work.. so I change where in I put `UpdateAttribute` processor which constructs the URL and places into another Flow attribute and then I use this attribute in my `invokeHTTP` processor.

Comment: Can you post the working template?